# Accessing HTTP Handler with UI-Router and MVC 5

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, angular-ui-router

I'm using a library that is submitting a "POST" request to a `.axd` path in my Angular application. Since I am using UI-Router, it seems that the `#/` appended to the URL is preventing the request from properly reaching the DLL.

The URL that needs to be reached in the library is:

`http://localhost:8080/MyApplication/MyArea/ModuleName#/ThermalLabelWebEditor.axd?_=1478731762000`

However, all I am getting back from this "POST" request is the HTML data of the page. I believe this is a symptom of MVC handling the path in its default manner, searching for a page matching the above URL, rather than accessing the DLL.

What I am trying to achieve is something along the lines of

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*anything}/ThermalLabelWebEditor.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

However, this is not valid in MVC.

Additionally, I've specified in my Area's `Web.config` file the `httpHandler`s required for this library, mainly:

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add path="ThermalLabelWebEditor.axd" verb="*" type="Neodynamic.Web.ThermalLabelEditor.ThermalLabelWebEditor"/>
...
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="TLWE" path="ThermalLabelWebEditor.axd" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="Neodynamic.Web.ThermalLabelEditor.ThermalLabelWebEditor" />
```

Now, I know that I can specify `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` in my Angular module's configuration. However, I would like to avoid doing this if at all possible, as it wouldn't solve the problem for older, non-HTML5 browsers that have to use the `#` fallback.

How can I configure my `Web.config` file for this Area (or for the entire MVC application) or the `RouteConfig.cs` to ensure that the request to `ThermalLabelWebEditor.axd` will successfully complete?

I'm using MVC 5, .NET 4.6, Angular 1.5.8, and UI-Router v0.3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much investigation, I have determined that this issue is only fixable on the JavaScript side. There appears to be no way to get IIS to parse `#` in the `path` section of the HTTP Handler, even with the use of wildcards. Due to the nature of how the `#` will short-circuit the URL, IIS is unable to route the request to the HTTP Handler, therefore handling the response instead with standard MVC that is breaking the application. Similarly, even with `routes.IgnoreRoute`, MVC cannot be configured to interpret the `#` character.

The solution to this issue is really just to parse the URL before sending the request and removing the `#`. With this in place, the handler mappings can be configured to look at the route in question `MyArea/MyModule/HttpHandler.axd...` and intercept with IIS before looking through the MVC structure.

I should note that the reason I am avoiding the use of HTML5 Mode in UI-Router is to preserve browser compatibility. If HTML5 Mode were enabled, the issue would be fixed for HTML5-compliant browsers. However, non-HTML5 browsers will fallback to the `#` in the URL, thus breaking the application.